# java monogdb connectivity issue how to use mongo connection pool for highest performance

Tags: java, mongodb, connection-pooling

I am learning mongodb with java. I have learned that mongo maintain internal connection pool. But I am little confused about my code, am I using connection pool in right way. Below is the methods in my mind to use connection pool safely. I have created mongoClient connection in static method.

```
class Config {
    public static MongoClient mongoClient = null;
    public static DB db = null;

    static{ 
        mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        db = mongoClient.getDB("myDBName");
    }
}
```

So, on every connection if i directly execute code.

```
config.db.getCollection("colletion name");
```

will it maintain connectio pool or should i get DB too in every connection?

```
db = mongoClient.getDB("myDBName");
db.getCollection("colletion");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're fine. The best way to use the connection pool, generally, is to pretend there is no connection pool. Just use the connection like it's one connection that your piece of code has to itself.

Comment: so, you mean to say that, if i store db object too in static variable it will work fine?

Comment: one more thing i want to clear , i am watching my console some how 8 connections are open i am using on single pc localhost. but connections are not closing itself can any one help??? its 2 hours when connection was open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is fine,

MongoDB drivers are written so advanced that they can handle multiple connections internally, i have to use connection like i am using single connection.